# How to browse Kubernetes documentation in a single HTML page?

Tags: kubernetes, documentation

I'm looking for a single page documentation for a given version of https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/.

Single page makes it easy for me to find where terms are defined without clicking around.

For example, [searching for `volumeMode`](https://kubernetes.io/search/?q=volumeMode) yields 8 different pages of results and makes me click each one to view the docs which is not ideal when one does not know the page structure well.

Worse, with https://devdocs.io/ the search does not parse page contents and yields nothing.

Does a single page documentation exist for Kubernetes?

Comment: Perhaps try to use `kubectl explain`.